# When I use the cnosdb cluster, I find that a single node failure will cause the write to fail. Why is this?

Tags: cnosdb

When I use the cnosdb 3meta+2data cluster, I created a database:

```
CREATE DATABASE db WITH replica 1;
```

and then wrote one row of data per second:

```
curl -s -XPOST -u 'root:' 'http://{tskv0_ip}:8902/api/v1/write?db=db5' -d 'ma,ta=a fa={count}'
```

After writing normally for 10s, I artificially filled the hard disk of one of the nodes. At this time, the other node was normal, but I found that the write failed. This is the error message:

```
{"error_code":"020000","error_message":"Unable to write file '/data/cnosdb/wal/_000001.wal': No space left on device (os error 28)"}
```

I think the other normal node should continue to work, but why is there an error?